# Selecting 2 corresponding columns in each row of a data frame

Tags: r, row, dataframe, vectorization

I apologize as this seems to be a basic question but I have been searching for a better solution but haven't found it. I have data of the following type.

```
myDATA<-data.frame(rbind(c("red","blue","green", "dog","hat","cat")
                     ,c("blue","green", "blue","dog","hat","cat")
                     ,c("green","blue","blue","dog","hat","cat")
                     ,c("green","red", "blue","dog","hat","cat")
                     )
               )
names(myDATA)<-c(paste("Color",1:3,sep=""),paste("Stim",1:3,sep=""))
myDATA$greenImage<-NA
```

Which gives:

myDATA

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|   Color1 Color2 Color3 Stim1 Stim2 Stim3 greenImage |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 1    red   blue  green   dog   hat   cat         NA |
| 2   blue  green   blue   dog   hat   cat         NA |
| 3  green   blue   blue   dog   hat   cat         NA |
| 4  green    red   blue   dog   hat   cat         NA |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

The `Color` columns correspond with the `Stim` columns by number, e.g., `Stim1` is displayed in `Color1` and so on. For each row, one `Stim` is displayed in green. I want to find that `Stim` and save in in a new column called `greenImage`.

I gather from a number of posts that `apply()` might be useful here but I have not been able to make it work. My rather inelegant solution has been a loop of the form below,

```
for (i in 1:nrow(myDATA)) {
  x <- match("green", unlist(myDATA[i,paste("Color", 1:3, sep="")]))
  myDATA[i,"greenImage"] <- as.character(myDATA[i, paste("Stim", x, sep="")])
}
```

Resulting in:

```
myDATA
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|   Color1 Color2 Color3 Stim1 Stim2 Stim3 greenImage |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 1    red   blue  green   dog   hat   cat        cat |
| 2   blue  green   blue   dog   hat   cat        hat |
| 3  green   blue   blue   dog   hat   cat        dog |
| 4  green    red   blue   dog   hat   cat        dog |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

However, the actual dataset has over 10000 rows so my solution is very inefficient. Can anyone suggest an alternative approach that is more efficient?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ifelse` to vectorize your comparisons:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  myDATA$greenImage = ifelse (myDATA[,i] == "green",
                              as.character(myDATA[,i+3]),
                              myDATA$greenImage)
}
```

Note that `as.character` is needed to get the string out of your `factor`'s. You can avoid that if  you use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating your `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the prompt reply. This was direct and effective. Much appreciated.